# ionic storekit Cannot finish a purchasing transaction , exception in webkit

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, storekit

I'm using ionic framework to build an iOS app. Currently, I'm adding in app purchase for a subscription. So far I've:

- Create an Identifier
- Create a Development Provisioning Profile
- Create a new app (using the Identifier)
- Create a purchase
- Added a dummy screenshot
- Create a test user in the sandbox mode
- Logout from iTunes from the settings (also tried to Reset all settings)
- followed the instructions here: https://github.com/AlexDisler/ng-storekit
- cordova build ios
- open with XCode and run on my device

Running the following code lists my products correctly:

```
  $storekit
    .setLogging(true)
    .load(['com.insiderai.ios.basic1'])
    .then(function (products) {
      console.log('products loaded', JSON.stringify(products));
    })
    .catch(function () {
      console.log('no products loaded');
    });
```

When I execute `$storekit.purchase("com.insiderai.ios.basic1");` from a controller The following error occurs:

```
2014-11-11 17:45:27.139 insider_ios[219:6335] InAppPurchase[objc]: About to do IAP
2014-11-11 17:45:27.140 insider_ios[219:6335] InAppPurchase[objc]: Transaction updated: com.insiderai.ios.basic1
2014-11-11 17:45:27.140 insider_ios[219:6335] InAppPurchase[objc]: Purchasing...
2014-11-11 17:45:27.141 insider_ios[219:6335] InAppPurchase[objc]: State: PaymentTransactionStatePurchasing
2014-11-11 17:45:27.145 insider_ios[219:6335] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Cannot finish a purchasing transaction
```

Any ideas of what to do? where to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in newer in app purchase plugin found here:

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/commit/22aef6f13c8fa7543a8c7883ca9e709ac82aa7ed

Comment: This worked. Now I'm getting exception in options.purchase: "TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_onPurchase(transactionId, productId)')"